# LinearLayout isn't shown when included in content layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `activity_pic.xml` layout which includes `content_pic.xml` to define the layout of my app. The activity_pic.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.olivia.myapplication.PicActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_pic" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`content_pic.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pick_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_text"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I include the line `<include layout="@layout/content_pic" />` within the `AppBarLayout` (that is, I move it up two lines) the button appears, and all the functionality of the button works. However when I put it after that, the button does not appear, and all I can see is the 'App Bar' bit of the layout.

Ok so the picture below shows how I would like it to look (and how the design view shows content_pic.xml)

[image: content_pic design view]

And here is what it actually looks like

[image: actual app]

However, when I put the `<include layout="@layout/content_pic" />` into the `AppBarLayout` I can see the button, as shown in the image below.

[image: content in AppBarLayout]

I have tried taking the content of `content_pic.xml` and including it directly instead of using the include statement, this still does not appear.

I've run out of ideas here - can anyone suggest what might be going wrong?

Comment: can you provide screenshots and more information, I don't understand what's the problem

Comment: do you want to put your content file outside of app bar layout?

Comment: Yes I want the button to appear outside of app bar layout but when I include it outside it doesn't display. I have provided more photos to illustrate the issues

Answer (score 0):

`AppBarLayout` works good if you us `NestedScrollView` or `RecyclerView`
so I suggest you change your content_pic.xml TO.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/pick_image_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_text"/>

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

     </LinearLayout>
```

I hope this will Help.

**EDIT**

You Just need to Change your `content_pic.xml` to this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

     <!-- Importent -->
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

          <LinearLayout
               xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="vertical" >

          <Button
               android:id="@+id/pick_image_button"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Hello" />

          <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/image_view"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried doing this but it doesn't seem to help, it's still not being displayed. I have added photos of what exactly I want to happen and things that work and don't work if that helps.